# When does the CentOS7 installer create a separate /home filesystem?

Tags: centos, partition, system-installation

I noticed when I install CentOS 7 (minimal install, accepting the defaults) in a virtual machine with an 8G drive, `/home` resides on the root filesystem. When I allocate an 80G drive, the installation creates separate `/home` and `/` filesystems. My question is, what is the minimum drive size beyond which the installer will create a separate filesystem for `/home` by default?

Comment: No, I'm asking about the default partitioning/filesystem scheme, not the minimum recommended space for /home. At what size does the installer say, "Ok, there's enough space for me to split things up".

Comment: Oh, I see. Wow, I didn't understand your question that way, but after your comment I see what you meant. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6):

This is really an interesting question.

The [rhinstaller code here](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda/blob/master/pyanaconda/installclass.py#L89), will give you a greater insight.

Looks like the split point is 50GiB for / and a minimum of 500 MiB for home, So since you allocated, `80G` for it, it possibly got 50G for `/` and the rest for `/home`.

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as how CentOS is a branch of RHEL, and the RHEL 7 documentation says 50GB, CentOS should be the same.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-disk-partitioning-setup-x86.html#sect-recommended-partitioning-scheme-x86

An excerpt:

```
/home partition - recommended size at least 1 GB

To store user data separately from system data, create a dedicated 
partition within a volume group for the /home directory. This partition 
should be sized based on the amount of data that will be stored locally, 
number of users, and so on. This will enable you to upgrade or reinstall 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux without erasing user data files. 

If your storage space is bigger than 50 GB, a /home partition will be created 
along with other partitions if you select automatic partitioning.
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Centos 7 and 6 the default is to have /home on the root-partion. The documentation says what you should create a separate partition and give /home a min. of 100MB space. But installer will not create separate partitions even if you use LVM. I use up to 60GB for system but Centos 7 / 6 never separated /home to another partition. I alway use the default with /home on /

Comment: Keeping home on its own filesystem makes upgrading, switching and mixing OS on the same box much easier. Seperating out filesystem with different usage profiles leads to better IO performance. Multiple smaller filesystems means smaller (but more frequent) fscks. Smaller filesystems means less data loss in the event of a major filesystem crash.